# MySQL-Python code adding `' to database name

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using MySQL-Python to create a database and grant privileges.

The user and database appear to be created correctly (at least judging by the fact there's a user and table with the correct names). The problem I found is with my grant all privileges command. It seems to be adding backticks to my database name, so when I do SHOW GRANTS it shows up as

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `'zojodesign'`.* TO 'zojodesign'@'127.0.0.1'
```

Checking another database user I created manually it shows SHOW GRANTS as

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `site`.* TO 'press'@'%
```

the code I'm using for MySQL-Python is

```
cur.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%s`.* TO %s@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY %s ", (domainShort, domainShort, mysqlpassword))
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't proper python (I'm a complete noob), but instead of using

```
`%s`
```

and using

```
cur.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON " +domainShort + ".* TO %s@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY %s ", (domainShort, mysqlpassword))
```

it works correctly.